# Castle Active Record NHibernate Sql Server Ce 3.5 (SqlServerCe) Problem Updating Schema

Tags: nhibernate, .net-3.5, schema, sql-server-ce, castle-activerecord

I am trying to Update Schema on SQL Server CE 3.5 using Active Record by Castle. I have encountered an error - exception on the bottom.

I believe it is not a new issue, but I could not find a walk around for this issue. When trying to Update Schema using Active Record I get an exception. It seems that there is a wrong GetSchema call. It should be System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.GetSchema() instead of DbConnection.GetSchema(). I got this information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333499/does-sql-server-ce-support-schema-update-with-nhibernate).

I am looking for resolution, not just information that it is MS problem. It is my problem right now, and possibly other people as well.

Exception:

`System.NotSupportedException: The method is not supported.`

`` in System.Data.Common.DbConnection.GetSchema(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
in NHibernate.Dialect.Schema.AbstractDataBaseSchema.GetTables(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String[] types)
in NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.GetTableMetadata(String name, String schema, String catalog, Boolean isQuoted)
in NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.GenerateSchemaUpdateScript(Dialect dialect, DatabaseMetadata databaseMetadata)
in NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean doUpdate) ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server CE 4.0 implements GetSchema(). If you can't upgrade I guess you're SOL...

Comment: Perfect. That fixed the update issue. However, using VS 2010 I could not look into the sdf file and I had to install addin that you can find at http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

The sdf 4.0 db browser is suppose to come with VS 2010 SP1.

Thanks Mauricio